# Create and save message in folder

Tags: thunderbird

I'm writing a Thunderbird extension and I wonder if there is a way to create a message and save it to some folder. Code would look like this.

```
create nsIMsgDBHdr header
header.subject = sub
header.from = from
header.to = to
header.body = body // although nsIMsgDBHdr doesen't have body attr
nsIMsgFolder folder
folder.save(header)
```

Right now I'm using kind a dirty way to do the job. I compose message for sending later, storing it in local outbox and then move it in given folder.

```
var localSrv = accountManager.FindServer("nobody", "Local Folders", "none");
var localAcc = accountManager.FindAccountForServer(localSrv);
var outbox = localSrv.rootFolder.getChildNamed("Outbox");
var inbox = server.rootFolder.getChildNamed("Inbox");
var account = accountManager.FindAccountForServer(server);

let compFields = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messengercompose/composefields;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgCompFields);
compFields.subject = subject;
compFields.from = fromAddr;
compFields.to = toAddr;
compFields.body = body;

let msgComposeParams = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messengercompose/composeparams;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgComposeParams);
msgComposeParams.composeFields = compFields;

let gMsgCompose = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messengercompose/compose;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgCompose);
gMsgCompose.initialize(msgComposeParams);
gMsgCompose.SendMsg(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgCompDeliverMode.Later,
                    account.defaultIdentity, // identity
                     account.key, // account
                     null, // message window
                     null); // nsIMsgProgress

let copyService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messenger/messagecopyservice;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgCopyService);

var jsMsgHdrArray = [];
var newestDate = -1;
var newestHdr;

for (let msgHdr in fixIterator(outbox.messages, Components.interfaces.nsIMsgDBHdr)) 
{
    if ( msgHdr.date > newestDate )
    {
        newestHdr = msgHdr;
        newestDate = msgHdr.date;
    }
}

jsMsgHdrArray.push(newestHdr);
let xpcomHdrArray = toXPCOMArray(jsMsgHdrArray, Components.interfaces.nsIMutableArray);  
copyService.CopyMessages(outbox, xpcomHdrArray, inbox, true, null, null, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of browsing mozilla code base i found satisfying solution.

```
let source = "From - Sat Nov  1 12:39:54 2008\n" +
             "X-Mozilla-Status: 0001\n" +
             "X-Mozilla-Status2: 00000000\n" +
             "Message-ID: <" + msgId + ">\n" +
             "Date: Wed, 11 Jun 2008 20:32:02 -0400\n" +
             "From: Tester <tests@mozillamessaging.invalid>\n" +
             "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" +
             "To: anna@example.com\n" +
             "Subject: " + aSubject + "\n" +
             "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\n" +
             "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" +
             "\n" + aBody + "\n";

folder.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgLocalMailFolder);
folder.addMessage(source);
```